# How to set background of the PDF page using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

So I am converting XML to PDF using XSLT.

I want to apply background color to whole page.

In case of

```
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="test"
              page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm"
          background-color="#ffaacc">
           <fo:region-body
              margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="1.3cm"
              background-color="#ffaacc"/>
           <fo:region-before extent="1.8cm" background-color="#ffaacc"/>
           <fo:region-after  extent="1.1cm" background-color="#ffaacc"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
```

If I do it this way I get a page with white background and header, footer, body rectangles with proper background...

so setting fo:simple-page-master element background-color attribute does not work the way I am using it.

So what would be the correct way? I do not want to use external stylesheet or something like that. I would like to set it the way I am setting it for the body/header/etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the extent to region-before to the full height of the page and set the background color on it. that would work in most conforming xsl fo engines.

Comment: note, you can remove all of the other colors, just region-before backgroun color and region-before extent = page-height

Comment: what about width?.. figured out width.. just set extent=page-height for fo:region-start and fo:region-end.. thanks